# git history log doesn't show branch

Tags: linux, git

We use git on linux, and use the git gui. I'm looking to clean up some branches that we may not need anymore.  I got a list of all the branches by selecting Branch->Checkout->Tracking Branch.  But when I search the history for several of those branches (trying to determine if they were merged back into master), nothing is found.  Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I figured it out.  Requesting log/history through the gui apparently only shows the history of those branches that you have worked on locally, not at origin.  I was able to get what I needed by using the command line and referencing origin/.